# A substitute to using a counter variable

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that works, however, I wanted to know if it was possible to make it better without using a counter variable. I have a map of "filters" and if there's at least one thing in the map i want to mutate my SQL string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT * from Table");

if (filters.size() >= 1) {
    int counter = 0;  //I don't want to use this

    for (String key : filters.keySet()) {
        if (counter == 0) {
            sb.append(" WHERE " + key + "=?");
            counter= 1;
            continue;
        }

        sb.append(" AND " + key + "=?");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Arnaud's solution is good in this specific case. In the more general case (i.e. not SQL queries), a boolean flag is preferable to an integer, e.g. `isFirstCondition`. You can get rid of the `continue` statement by using an `else`.

Comment: It would still account to the same thing, I was wondering if there is a workaround to using any `bools` or `ints`.

Comment: Yes and no. It's significantly better, in that it gives the identifier a meaningful name, simplifies the `if` condition, and restricts the set of possible values. Again, in the *general case*, that is the way to accomplish iterating over a collection while doing something special on the first iteration. You want not *want* to use it but, in another situation, you may not have a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string joiner, which allows setting an empty value, which will allow you to not include the "WHERE" when your set is empty.

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" AND ", " WHERE ", "");
joiner.setEmptyValue("");

filters.keySet().stream().map( key -> key + " = ?" ).forEach(joiner::add);

String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE" + joiner.toString();
```

Alternative without stream:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("=? AND ", " WHERE ", "=?");
joiner.setEmptyValue("");

filters.keySet().forEach(joiner::add);

String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE" + joiner.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: The request is vulnerable to SQL injection if keys are provided by a client. They should be sanitized.

You can use the `"1 = 1"` trick.

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT * from Table WHERE 1 = 1");
for(String key : filters.keySet()){
  sb.append(" AND " + key + "=?");
}
```

(same goes with `"0 = 1"` if you want to chain some `OR` statements instead).

Comment: That works great, but something else, because this is work related and `where 1 = 1` will not do justice.

Comment: @Michael VERY good point. I saw the prepared statement but forgot the key.

Comment: @caitlinp The `1 = 1` trick is pretty normal. I've used it at work many times.

Comment: That would be my go to solution, if I'm not able to get a different/better by the end of the day. @marstran